# TypeError("Data type not understood") when trying to create a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sympy

I am trying to differentiate a set of equations using sympy and I have to create a 2x2 matrix with the derivatives I calculate. This is my code:

```
#import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from scipy import *
from sympy import *

x1 = 3; x2 = 0; x3 = 0; x4 = 3
y1 = 3; y2 = 3; y3 = 0; y4 = 0

s = Symbol('s')
t = Symbol('t')

N1 = (s+1)*(t+1)/4
N2 = (1-s)*(t+1)/4
N3 = (1-s)*(1-t)/4
N4 = (s+1)*(1-t)/4

x = (x1*N1)+(x2*N2)+(x3*N3)+(x4*N4)
y = (y1*N1)+(y2*N2)+(y3*N3)+(y4*N4)

dxs = diff(x, s)
dxt = diff(x, t)
dys = diff(y, s)
dyt = diff(y, t)

#print type(dxs).__name__

print dxs, dxt, dys, dyt

J = Matrix([dxs, dys], [dxt, dyt])
#J = np.matrix((dxs, dys), (dxt, dyt))
print J
```

However, I get a "data type not found" error. So, I tried using the type() function to print the data type of the derivatives I end up with. I got two different types. The type() returns 'Rational' when the final derivative is just numbers. It returns 'Add' when the final derivative has the variables 's' or 't' in it (This can be done by giving non zero values for x2, x3, y3 and y4). If anyone can help me with creating this matrix, I will be so thankful. I also tried using

```
J = Matrix[[dxs, dys], [dxt, dyt]]
```

instead of

```
J = Matrix((dxs, dys), (dxt, dyt))
```

and now I get 'type' object has no attribute `'__getitem__'` error. I am very new to python and I have tried all I could to find a solution to this online but I failed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like `J = Matrix(((dxs, dys), (dxt, dyt)))` (or `Matrix([[dxs, dys], [dxt, dyt]])`, `Matrix([(dxs, dys), (dxt, dyt)])`, etc.).  What you are doing is passing the `Matrix` constructor two tuples, while you need to pass it a single tuple of tuples (or list of lists, or list of tuples, etc.).  So in other words, a 2D data structure rather than two 1D data structures.

Also, don't do `from foo import *`.  Especially with numpy and sympy this will cause collisions (for example both provide a `diff` function).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Sorry for wasting anyone's time. I used the wrong syntax when defining the matrix. Instead of

```
J = Matrix([dxs, dys], [dxt, dyt])
```

I should have used

```
J = Matrix([[dxs, dys], [dxt, dyt]])
```